# Flink automatic / programatic savepoints

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

[FLIP-10](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-10%3A+Unify+Checkpoints+and+Savepoints) talks about "periodic savepoints" see quote below.

This seems to imply some means to achieve periodic automatic save points.

Does flink support a feature that allows a job to periodically cause a save point of itself to be taken?

If not then ...

1) what is the meaning of the paragraph below

2) what is the state of the art for arranging for a job to be periodically save pointed?

> Periodic Savepoints
>
> Allow the user to configure periodic triggering of savepoints. The behaviour should be similar to manually triggering savepoints periodically. Furthermore, we bound the number of available periodic savepoints. On shut down, they are never removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The periodic savepoint part of FLIP-10 was not implemented, but the REST api call and command line interface for taking savepoints are available. Seems like you could use one of these in combination with a cron job to take periodic savepoints.

See FLIP-47 for an indication of where future work in this general area is currently heading.

UPD: In 2023 flink apache operator is able to run scheduled savepoints, [see](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/docs/custom-resource/job-management/#periodic-savepoint-triggering)

Answer (score 0):

How hard would it be for the app itself to make those calls?

I don't want to have to run and monitor another component